# nginx sends duplicate header

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

In my `nginx.conf` file I define a header on the http level

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=86400; includeSubDomains" always;
```

When I check the network response headers in chrome dev tools, it shows 2 of those headers

```
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
strict-transport-security: max-age=86400; includeSubDomains
```

Notes:

- In my config file I only use `add_header` once.
- I also have no include directive
- I cannot find another `nginx.conf` file in the nginx-docker image

Questions:

- Any idea where the 2nd header can come from?
  i.e. some default or some inheritance from another config file)
- Maybe any idea how I could debug this?

Comment: Rather than use the browser, you should use `curl -I ...` to debug the server. The command `nginx -T` will show you the entire configuration. If this server is talking to an upstream service (e.g. PHP), the application may also be providing headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks @RichardSmith for the great comment.

- `nginx -T` is really great for testing, as it will show the full configuration (with all includes, etc.)
- `curl -I` also showed both headers (to make sure that the browser does not used any cache, etc.)
- in deed the 2nd header was sent from the upstream server - and then nginx added the one I defined in the `nginx.conf`

Comment: Hi @TmTron, how did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same trouble because if I use add_header on location error says duplicate headers, but if I remove them it errors out on missing headers. What do you mean by 2nd header was sent from upstream server? how did you control this or remove this additional duplicate header?

Comment: Our app used express and helmet. for helmet we set `hsts: false` so that it does not send the HSTS headers.